# How to change author profile name in Google Scholar?

Tags: personal-name, google-scholar

I would like to change my author profile name after a divorce in Google Scholar. I tried to open a new account with my maiden name but I couldn't When I entered my current account on Google, it doesn't give me any fields to be able to write my maiden name. Is there a way to edit or change it easily?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia, but a use-case of google scholar.

Comment: @user3209815 I'm voting to leave open since it's something that many academics will want to do.

Answer (score 5):

While signed in, visit [My Citations](https://scholar.google.com/citations) in Google Scholar.

Click on the "Edit" button next to your name to change the name in your author profile.

Click "Save" after you have made your changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is another question that if I can still keep seeing my current publications ?

Comment: Yes, you will see your publication as it is.@Cigdem Yildirim